# Best way to preserve SSD health when performing routine delete operations?

Tags: optimization

I'm coding an application with a mechanism that performs routine disk cleanup (on smartphone devices, which all use solid-state drives). I want to limit the disk usage to a certain threshold and see two approaches:

1. Whenever disk usage goes above the threshold by even a single byte, delete as many files as needed until usage is below the threshold. This means fewer delete operations per run but the task itself will be performed more frequently.
2. Whenever disk usage goes above the threshold by a certain factor (i.e. 1.5x), delete as many files as needed until usage is below the threshold. This means more delete operations per run but the task itself will be performed less frequently.

Apple Developer guidelines explicitly warns developers against wearing out the SSD by performing unnecessary write and delete operations. Is there a difference between the two approaches above in terms of preserving the health of the SSD?

Comment: (This seems a perfect problem to wet one's feet in *simulation*.)